# HTML canvas - custom getImageData values, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is possible to get e.g. `alt` attribute from image drawed in canvas?

http://jsfiddle.net/DV9Bw/1/

`getImageData` returning colors of the image. Can I modify `getImageData` to store `alt` attribute of image?

Comment: `getImageData` will provide the red, green, blue and alpha information for every pixel in the image. there is no meta information embedded inside it. Apart from that, an `alt` attribute does technically have nothing to do with the image itself, it's a semantic description of it. Are you by any chance looking for a way to load an image into canvas _and_ preserve the original `alt` for that image (if any) so you can use those later on?

Comment: [`alt`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_attribute) is an attribute of HTML element (not only image). `getImageData` returns **pixel data** of canvas area. So it's quite obvious that these two things are totally unrelated.

Comment: You can define an `alt` attribute on your canvas element with `example.setAttribute('alt','myAltValue')` then you can fetch that attribute with `example.getAttribute('alt')`, but as commented above, `getImageData` has nothing to do with the `alt` attribute

Comment: thanks for comments, now I know that's not possible. @markE I want alt of any image in canvas but thanks :). I asked if is possilbe to store any custom parameter in `getImageData` object.